# Should I store JWT tokens in IndexedDB?

Tags: cookies, jwt

After reading some articles, I realize that using localStorage and sessionStorage is a bad idea for storing JWT tokens, and cookies with `httpOnly` should be used instead.

As I read more and learn some about indexedDB today, I wonder if indexedDB is a secure option for storing JWT tokens as well?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is NO, as you are pretty much convinced using localStorage and sessionStorage is a bad idea.  IndexedDB is also vulnerable to cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks similar to local storage.

**Regardless of security** -

1. IndexedDB API is powerful but may seem too complicated (I'd go so far as to say 'horrific') for simple use cases such as storing jwt token. Because, even for this implementation, you will have to write more code. (More code, which means maybe more bugs). Just be aware of the steep learning curve when you're getting started with it.
2. IndexDB is not actually designed for such use cases. It is designed to work with significantly larger amounts of structured data. For basic key-value operations, IndexedDB performance takes a hit.
3. Browser support for IndexedDB isn't also quite good.

Comment: Well said indexed db is used mostly for storing data most of time when you are building pwa so if client is offline you can access it